# Why opencv does not recognizes cascade xml trained using opencv_traincascade.exe format?

Tags: xml, opencv, cascade, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I have trained two cascade.xml train one using opencv_traincascade.exe and the other using opencv_haartraining.exe. When i use the first xml (image)[trained with opencv_traincascade.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbRL9.png) it shows error **"Unspecified error (The node does not represent  a user object (unknown type?)"** , but the second xml works fine (image)[Haarcascade trained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YmK1.png), but bad results. 
I notice both xml have different formats.. anyone can please..?

Comment: Were you really interested in getting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the formats are different. Furthermore with traincascade.exe you used LBP features that are not supported by haartraining.exe and old APIs.
You have to load the newer cascade (trained with traincascade) with the new method.

```
CascadeClassifier cascade;
cascade.load( “cascadefile.xml” )
```

Comment: Thanks.. Do you have any idea about how to implement SURF algo with Flann in emgucv .. please help me if you can, i want to compare multiple images with a single source image in run time.